# How can I encrypt files from request post with gpg

Tags: python, file, post, encryption, gnupg

Is possible encrypt files from request post? How?

```
files = request.FILES[files]
gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='/home/XXXX/.gnupg')
gpg.encrypt(files) <-- This do exception
```

Exception:

> 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: What is the exact error message ?

Comment: Exception is:'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#encryption) you should pass a string to encrypt(), not a file. encrypt() is certainly trying to get the encoded string by trying to call [.encode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) on the argument.

You can find an example of encrypting a file [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/#encrypt-file).

Comment: But I use a absolute path with a file binary it works

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
def encrypt(self, files):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/XXXX/.gnupg')        
    encrypted = gpg.encrypt_file(files, recipients='mail@mail.com', passphrase='secret')
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    name = f.name
    f.write(encrypted.data)
    f.close()
    return open(name, 'r+b')      

def decrypt(self, files):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/XXXX/.gnupg')    
    result = gpg.decrypt(files.content).data
    return result
```